# PHP to js-PHP solution in order to avoid pageloads

Tags: php, javascript, httprequest

In order to decrease pageloads I would like to change my current solution. Below is a part of the code that I use to give the user the booktitle from a isbn. The script takes the isbn, posted from a form and checks its isbn validity and then uses a open api solution where a http request is mde with the isbn and the title is returned as json and then displayed for the user.

The user usually checks three books and, with the current solution, have to post the form for each book to get the result. How is the best way to do this without pageloads?

```
if(isset($_POST['isbn']) && strip_tags($_POST['isbn'])!=''){

        $currISBN = new ISBNtest;
        $currISBN->set_isbn(strip_tags($_POST['isbn']));

        if ($currISBN->valid_isbn13() === TRUE) {

            //Hämta info
            $url = "http://apisite.com/search?query=isbn:".$currISBN->get_isbn13()."&format=json";
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.site.com");
            $json_body = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            $json = json_decode($json_body,true);
            $this_title=$json["xsearch"]["list"][0]["title"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a job for jQuery.ajax()!
http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

If you have a little bit of programming under your belt, it shouldn't take too long to figure out how to implement it.

Comment: You should mention that jQuery is a pretty "big" javascript library, and does way more than just .ajax() - Using it for the sole purpose of async requests might be a bit overkill.

Comment: I have the library already for other functions so Im glad to hear I can use it here too. My knowledge is limited to the jquery select and show/hide functions though soo I guess it will be a challenge ! :)

Comment: @caimz it might be, but why reinvent the wheel for an AJAX wrapper?  jQuery is possibly the best wrapper for it on the net today.

Comment: It might be the best (in its class), personally i prefer Prototype, but these doesn't play well together. Either way, he is already using jquery so then it's a nobrainer. use jquery's functions and it should be straight forward.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a prime example for using XMLHTTPRequest in the background - and some javascript that puts some data on the page. You would not need to pageload at all.

Comment: I looked it up, thanks. Whats the difference to the other mentioned jquery async?

Comment: XMLHTTPRequest is the core of what jquery wraps in helper code (ajax). Wrapper code will enable you to care about higher level code, not having to worry about browser differences (mostly) - and other convenient functions to write less, do more.